# AWK: How to load a file into array and store the final results into another array

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, awk

I have an `input` file with the below content

```
child, parent, val
1  , 0  , a
2  , 1  , b
3  , 1  , c
4  , 2  , d
5  , 2  , e
```

I need to store them in an array named `data_array` by directly reading from the file without the header. Something like this

```
BEGIN {
while (getline < "input")
{
split($0,ft,",");
child=ft[1];
parent=ft[2];
value=ft[3];
#need help here in assigning two values into the array
data_array[child]=parent,value;
}
close("input");
}
```

The result_array holds the parent to child relationship with ordering.

```
result_array[parent]="all children separated by comma"
```

For example, parent 0 has one child called 1. Parent 1 has two children called 2, and 3. 
The order of 2 and 3 are determined by alphabetically sorting the corresponding values. 
Since the sorting of values results in `b` followed by `c` the array element should have 2,3.
There could be any number of children.
Childless nodes must be written with blank content.
These results must go into the final array in the following format.

**Need help on this part to convert the data_array into the result_array**

```
result_array["0"] = "1"
result_array["1"] = "2,3"
result_array["2"] = "4,5"
result_array["3"] = ""
result_array["4"] = ""
result_array["5"] = ""
```

Please shout if this is unclear.

Comment: You can use `NR > 1` to skip the first line, but the `data_array` here seems to be an map instead of an array

Comment: If you're ever considering using `getline` make sure you read and fully understand http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline first to understand when and how to use it. [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input AND expected output so we can help you do whatever you are trying to do the right way.

Comment: @EdMorton my experience tells me awk.getline is very tricky.... I found the linked doc also in one of your comments. It is a Must-Read getline guideline . Now I pick getline only if I have to..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays and sorted_in:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=" *, *" }
NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) f[$i]=i; next }
{ parentsChildren2Vals[$(f["parent"])][$(f["child"])] = $(f["val"]) }
END {
    for (parent in parentsChildren2Vals) {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_str_asc"
        for (child in parentsChildren2Vals[parent]) {
            parents2children[parent] = (parent in parents2children ?
                        parents2children[parent] "," : "") child
            children[child]
        }
    }

    for (child in children) {
        parents2children[child]
    }

    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
    for (parent in parents2children) {
        printf "parents2children[\"%s\"] = \"%s\"\n", parent, parents2children[parent]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
parents2children["0"] = "1"
parents2children["1"] = "2,3"
parents2children["2"] = "4,5"
parents2children["3"] = ""
parents2children["4"] = ""
parents2children["5"] = ""
```

Comment: It errors `awk: tst.awk:3: { parentsChildren2Vals[$(f["par"])][$(f["Chl"])] = $(f["val"]) }
awk: tst.awk:3:                                    ^ syntax error
awk: tst.awk:3: { parentsChildren2Vals[$(f["par"])][$(f["Chl"])] = $(f["val"]) }
awk: tst.awk:3:                                                ^ syntax error
awk: tst.awk:7:         for (child in parentsChildren2Vals[parent]) {
awk: tst.awk:7:                                           ^ syntax error
`

Comment: Then you copy/pasted wrong or you are not using GNU awk 4.* for true multi-dimensional arrays. If the latter (`awk --version`), get it.

Comment: Yep, mine is `GNU Awk 3.1.5`

Comment: That's a prehistoric gawk missing a TON of extremely useful functionality (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History). Get an updated version.

Comment: I will upgrade and test. BTW is this powerful to handle millions of such records from the file? (may be 15 million in one file)

Comment: Depends how much memory you have since it's going to read the whole file into memory before it starts processing. If you tell me it has 6 Giga-Jillions of memory I will not be able to tell you if that's enough or not, sorry, you'd have to try it or ask someone else.

Comment: You made a mistake copy/pasting the script.

Comment: You changed the names of the columns in the header line. You originally had the first line of the input file specify the column names of `Chl , par , val` and so that's what I use in the script to get the field numbers `parentsChildren2Vals[$(f["par"])][$(f["Chl"])] = $(f["val"])`. Now you've changed those names to `child, parent, val` but you didn't update the script to use the new names so `f["par"]` and `f["Chi"]` are no longer populated so `$(f["par"])` and `$(f["Chi"])` are both the same as `$0` so each of them evaluates to the whole input line. I edited the script to use your new names.

Comment: Understood. Perfect. I swapped the columns by mistake. Now all clear.